# Check function() return without double alert

Tags: jquery

So I have a function that check some values:

```
function validC(){
    if ($("#idss").val() == 'cc' && ts_mm < m && ts_yy == y) {
        alert('Please fix it!.');
        $('#in_fo_ar').focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

So then later and before I execute my Ajax I check what the result from that function was..

```
var rty = validC();
if (rty != false) {
    // Execute my ajax
}
```

So when I click on Submit, it tells me "Please fix it!" which is fine, but it shows 2 alerts with the same message... is there was no errors then it execute the ajax/script and all fine.. so how can I prevent from double alerts, well, in this case alerts is what I use to let the user know whats going on... 
or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Paste your HTML code also

Comment: Please share few of your code